# SimpleXML OutOfMemory error in Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, simple-framework

I'm using Simple 2.4.1 library in my Android project. I got this OutOfMemory error when trying to process an XML file of 700 kB (~6k lines) - process here means read the file, do some calculations, and then write the result to a new file. It worked fine with a 600 kB file, at least I haven't got the same error yet.

Here's how the XML looks like:

```
<items>
    <item1 id="1">
        <subitem1 id="1">
            <subsubitem1 id="a">
                <iteminfo>
                    <info>blublub</info>
                    <info>blublub</info>
                </iteminfo>
            </subsubitem1>
            <subsubitem1 id="b">
                <iteminfo>
                    <info>blublub</info>
                    <info>blublub</info>
                </iteminfo>
            </subsubitem1>
        </subitem1>
    </item1>
</items>
```

Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may simply be a case of holding too much in memory without doing something with it. If you think about it, if you are reading a file into memory that is 700kb, and you add in overheads for the rest of the xml parsing, your application, and other applications that will want some memory and CPU time on the device, it boils down to this not being a good idea.

There isn't a workaround as such, any that you find would not be very good from a programming sense, because you are still trying to hold 700kb of xml in memory, when you probably do not need most of that.

I suggest that you find a way of removing this data from memory as soon as you can to free up resources. You could save the elements you find in a meaningful way to file or something and index via database, which would allow you to hold large amounts of data, but instead of holding onto it all in memory, you can look up in the database for the data you want specifically, and only bring that back in to memory. This way you limit your use of resources, and people who download you application won't get suspicious when you are using up a lot of their memory.

Comment: What I'm currently doing is: using a nested loop to iterate through `items`object, get `iteminfo`object and do something with the children. The result is then inserted into `iteminfo` as a child element. I set `info` to null to reduce file size and saved everything into a new file. Ok, I think I can see how I got this OutOfMemory error now.. Unfortunately, database is not an option for me, so I guess I'll have to rewrite my logic. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 1):

I have never used SimpleXML, but it is my understanding that they went to a DOM-based parsing method to deserialize the XML somewhere around version 2.3 to reduce the previous dependency that they had on the StAX framework.  Simple is also a JavaSE library, not optimized for mobile.  Unfortunately, these two things often go hand in hand with OutOfMemoryError.

I won't claim that the XML you're parsing is by any means a "huge" file, but it is substantial. Depending on what else your program is using memory for at the time, you may be topping out the heap.  Here are a couple of rules of thumb to keep in mind:

- Expect that on many devices your available size is no more than 16MB for the entire application.  This is closer to 24MB on some newer devices, but for a long time 16MB was the standard heap size.
- I haven't seen any numbers published from Simple, but traditionally a fully loaded DOM will require approximately 4x the size in memory of the XML it came from (~3MB in your case).  If you're getting this XML from a remote location, it's probably also still in memory at the same time for a period.

It sounds like whatever else is going on in your program at the time is enough to eat up all but a few MB of the heap, and you may be right on the edge with whatever platform you are testing on.

If you are relatively sure that you cannot clear memory usage elsewhere during this operation in your application, I would recommend switching to a stream-based parsing library that uses SAX or Pull.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: I'm using Archos 7, available system storage 29 MB and internal flash storage 6 GB. The XML file is saved in the external storage. Well, I guess I eat up a lot of memory during data processing then. Thanks! and +1 for another enlightenment.

Comment: @blubblub: Not storage space, storage is irrelevant to the running of your application.  Heap space is RAM, and pretty much all Android devices are governed to the same value by the system.  The Archos runs 2.2, so it is probably closer to the 24MB mark.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SAX parser instead of parsing the entire XML document at once. SAX parsers read the XML document as a stream and appropriate events are fired when a particular tag is reached. It's not as convenient as using something like SimpleXML.

Here's a tutorial which might help: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: Yes, I've tried those steps mentioned there. I decide to go with SimpleXML as it is really convenient to serialize and deserialize into POJO. But I've never tested it against a "big" file, until now. Thanks anyway!